# Using namespaces instead of requiring each class separately

Tags: php, oop, architecture, namespaces

This is my `init.php` file required by the `index.php` file:

```
<?php 

/** 
*
*   Initialization file: Will require all components we need. 
*
**/


/* Set session */
session_start();                                                // Start session

/* Helpers */
require_once 'helpers/Sanitize.php';                            // Sanatizing (escaping) strings 
require_once 'helpers/Token.php';                               // Generate tokens 
require_once 'helpers/Hash.php';                                // Hash class
require_once 'helpers/Input.php';                               // Inputs manipulations
require_once 'helpers/Validation.php';                          // Validation class
require_once 'helpers/Redirect.php';                            // Redirect helper 
require_once 'helpers/Session.php';                             // Session manipulations 
require_once 'helpers/Cookie.php';                              // Cookies manipulations 


/* Core */
require_once 'core/Config.php';                                 // Default global vairables 
require_once 'core/App.php';                                    // Load App class from CORE
require_once 'core/Controller.php';                             // Load Controller class from CORE 
require_once 'core/Database.php';                               // Load Database class 


/* Models */
require_once '/www/myapp/models/System_user.model.php';     // System User Model
require_once '/www/myapp/models/user/User.model.php';           // User Model
require_once '/www/myapp/models/exec/something_usage.model.php';            // something model
require_once '/www/myapp/models/abc/abc.model.php';         // A class for handling trees 
require_once '/www/myapp/models/Group.model.php';           // Group Model
require_once '/www/myapp/models/banana.model.php';          // A class for handling trees 
// require_once '/www/myapp/models/Tree_db.php';            // A class for handling trees
```

As you can see, I am reacquiring all my classes files which is bad practice.
After a small research I found out that there is a function that autoloads classes whenever it is called:

```
// /* Autoload classes from directory */
// spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
//  require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';  // No such directory
// });
```

I couldn't use it since my classes aren't in one folder and not easy to navigate to.

I continued my research and [found out I can use a composer command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGSerlMoIrY) `composer dump-autoload -o` that can require my code by declaring `namespaces` in the top of every class (following the folder structure) and `use` when using a specific class, and requiring `autoload.php` instead of the list mentioned above:

```
/* Composer */
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';  // Loading composer components
```

I applied this change to all my classes - controllers classes files, models classes files (and subfolders classes files), core classes and database classes.

Example: 
having the folder `/www/app/models/system_users.model.php`
I added the namespace `App\Models;` (and the class name is `System_users`), and if this class object is instantiated in an other class I use `use App\Modal\System_uses;` at the top of the file.

But I keep getting this error msg:

```
[22-Oct-2018 12:27:31] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Config' not found in /www/app/views/login/pages-login.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /www/app/core/Controller.php(51): require_once()
#1 /www/app/controllers/login.php(27): app\Core\Controller->view('login/pages-log...')
#2 [internal function]: app\Controllers\Login->index()
#3 /www/app/core/App.php(51): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /www/public/index.php(15): app\Core\App->__construct()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /www/app/views/login/pages-login.php on line 14
[22-Oct-2018 12:27:31] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller' not found in /www/app/controllers/Error_404.php on line 7
[22-Oct-2018 12:27:31] PHP Stack trace:
[22-Oct-2018 12:27:31] PHP   1. {main}() /www/public/index.php:0
[22-Oct-2018 12:27:31] PHP   2. app\Core\App->__construct() /www/public/index.php:15
[22-Oct-2018 12:27:31] PHP   3. require_once() /www/app/core/App.php:31
```

Might be because I'm not requiring my `Config` class in the views. But up until now using `requre once` everything worked fine, and i really find it bothering using `use App\Core\Config;` in top of every view.

How is the proper way to handle this kind of situation with namespaces?

**EDIT:**

Im adding my code structure:

/www/public/index.php

```
<?php 
use MyApp\Core\App;


/** 
*
*   Index: First page a user visits. 
*
**/

# Reuiring init.php: Responsible for initializing classes we want to use.
require_once '../myapp/init.php'; 

# Initialize App class
$app = new App();
```

/www/myapp/core/controller.php

```
<?php 
namespace MyApp\Core;
use MyApp\Models\System_user;
use MyApp\Core\Config;

/**
 *
 *  Controller instance: 
 *
 */
class Controller
{

/*=================================
=            Variables            =
=================================*/

    # System User 
    protected $system_user;



/*===============================
=            Methods            =
================================*/


    /**
     *
     *  Model Class: Loads a requested model
     *  @param  $model      String      Gets a model name
     *  
     */
    protected function model($model)
    {
        require_once '../myapp/models/' . $model . '.php';
        return new $model();
    }


    /**
     *
     *  View Class: Loads a requested view
     *  @param  $view       String      Gets a view name 
     *  @param  $data       Array       (optional) Gets an array of variables to pass to the view
     *  @throws                         Plain view 
     *
     */
    protected function view($view, $data=[])
    {
        require_once '../myapp/views/' . $view . '.php';
    } 


    /**
     *
     *  Check if a user is logged in
     *
     */
    protected function is_loggedin()
    {   

        ... 
    }
```

/www/myapp/core/app.php

```
<?php 
namespace MyApp\Core;
// use MyApp\Core\Controller;
use MyApp\Controllers;
/**
 *
 *  App instance: Handles controlles (specifically gets routs data)
 *
 */
class App 
{

    protected $controller   = 'Error_404';
    protected $method       = 'index';
    protected $parameters   = array();
    protected $contollerNamespace;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        # Get parsed URL
        $url    = $this->parseUrl();

        # Check if contorller via input-url exists in the controller folder
        if (file_exists('../myapp/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')){
            $this->controller = $url[0];    // Replace current 'home' controller with the new one
            $this->contollerNamespace = 'MyApp\\Controllers\\'.$url[0];
            unset($url[0]);                 // Remove controller name from the array. 
        }

        # Require the controllers class via controllers folder
        require_once '../myapp/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

        # Create a new obect of the controller (by its name)
        $this->controller = new $this->contollerNamespace; // ex: new Home() -- or: new Login() 

        # Chech if method is passed
        if ( isset($url[1]) ) {

            # Check if method exists in class
            if ( method_exists($this->controller, $url[1]) ) {
                # Set new method variable
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        # Set parameters (if any).
        $this->parameters = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        # Summon controller with the relevant method and variables.
        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->parameters);

    }


    /**
     *
     *  Parses the url - Gets the $_GET input via .htaccess definition. 
     *
     */ 
    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['url']) ) {

            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        }
    }

}
```

/www/myapp/controllers/login.php

```
<?php 
namespace MyApp\Controllers;
use MyApp\Core\Controller;
use MyApp\Models\System_user;
use MyApp\Core\Config;

/**
 * Login Class
 */
class Login extends Controller
{


    /**
     *
     * Login Main login Form
     *
     */
    public function index($name ='')
    {   
        // Create a new system user
        $system_user = new System_user();
        // If user is logged in - Redirect to dashboard
        if ( $system_user->check_logged_in() )
            Redirect::to('dashboard');          // Redirect to login form
        else
            $this->view('login/pages-login');   // Redirect to login form
    }


    /**
     *
     *  User login: Creates the user login. 
     *
     */
    public function user_login()
    {
        ...

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Composer runs on the PSR-4 autoloading standard.

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

In your `composer.json`, add an autoloader namespace for your classes. For example, in my form package, it looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Del\\Form\\": "src/",
      "DelTesting\\Form\\": "tests/unit/Del/Form/"
    }
},
```

What is this saying? Esentially all classes in `src/` will have namespace `Del\Form`.

So, for instance, `src/Form.php` would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Del\Form;

class Form 
{
    // code
}
```

Take note, the classname should match the filename, that is class `Form` should be called `Form.php`.

Now if you create folders in `src`, those get added to the namespace. Another example, `src/Field/Text.php` would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Del\Form\Field;

class Text
{
    // code
}
```

If you stick to these conventions, everything will autoload.

After editing `composer.json` to add the namespace, run `composer dumpautoload` to generate the classmaps that composer uses.

Comment: All of this is well understood. The main question regards of the proper architecture while calling a view file.

Comment: Have you added `use My\Whatever\Config;` at the top of the classes, you'll need that

Comment: Also, paste the autoload section in `composer.json`

Comment: Yes, the example I gave included the login class where I have on the top of the login controller `use App\Core\Config`

Comment: Unless you are trying to instantiate classes in your view, you should be creating them elsewhere and just pass those variables to the view

Comment: `/www/app/models/system_users.model.php` does not follow PSR-4. If the full classname is `App\Models\System_users` then it should be `/www/app/models/System_users.php`. Namespace `App` is set to `/www/App` in `composer.json`? Again, paste the autoload section so we can see!

Comment: Also you have `Models`. Did you mean `Model`? You also refer to `Modal`.

Comment: Good catch! if forgot about those (I only yesterday started moving to this kind of structure..) - but I still get the view error. I think i'm going to add to my post the whole general files architecture for maybe a better reference

Comment: If you pass vars into your view, you wont need use statements, you'll just have various $variables ready to use. Try not to put PHP logic in views, only loops and echoes where possible!

Comment: look here https://github.com/delboy1978uk/form/blob/master/composer.json#L18-L22 and then browse here to see how I've set my things up https://github.com/delboy1978uk/form/tree/master/src

Comment: hmm.. I used to work with codeigniter which works that way, I created a config class where I use Config::someVar and get the variable directly from anywhere.. just found this useful for constant vars... Is that considered bad practice? (I edited my main post with files and contents) - I'll take a look at your repos in a moment